# Configure NLog to write log to Azure SQL server with manage Identity token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, nlog, azure-virtual-machine

I am using NLog and writing log messages to the database using an ADO.NET provider.

I have enabled managed Identity for my Server and I want to connect with Managed Identity and write the logs in Azure SQL. I have SP in nlog configuration file.

How can I achieve this?
What change is required in nlog configuration file?

- NLog version: 4.6.6
- Platform: . .NET Core 2
- Need to log error with Managed Identity in Azure SQL

Edit- 
Further I have tried to build the databasetarget by code.But not able to set up the accesstoken. 
It is throwing error

> Keyword not supported: ',access_token'.

```
LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));
string connectionString = "Data Source=servername.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=dbname;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.AccessToken = accessToken;
conn.Open();
var databaseTarget = (DatabaseTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("database");
databaseTarget.ConnectionString = string.Format("{0},access_token ={1}", connectionString, conn.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Have you tried to setup a connectionstring with the wanted identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#configure-a-connection-string-for-an-azure-storage-account

Comment: I am using Azure sql to store log and nlog documentation doesnot have anything for paremeterized the identity token in their documentation. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

Comment: NLog DatabaseTarget requires that you use ConnectionString to setup authentication. Have you tried asking Microsoft whether Azure SQL can be used with Ado-ConnectionString?

Comment: hi Rolf,I can connect with Azure Sql using SqlConnection of System.Data.SqlClient. SqlConnection support acces_token property. The similar things I am not able to find in DatabaseTarget class of NLog.Targets.  I am using 4.6.6 of NLog class.

Comment: NLog DatabaseTarget is not Azure SQL specific. So not possible to set `SqlConnection.acces_token` directly, unless it can be done using ConnectionString.

Comment: I am trying to set the access token in connection string . But it is throwing error Keyword not supported: ',access_token'. Here access token is not supported by DatabaseTarget of nlog. ALso I am not able to find any Azure sql connection string with access_token

Answer (score 4):

NLog 4.7 has now been released with support for assigning DbConnection properties like AccessToken. The AccessToken can be acquired using this nuget-package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureAccessToken/

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureAccessToken" /> 
</extensions>

<targets>
  <target xsi:type="Database" connectionString="...">
    <dbProvider>Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
    <connectionProperty name="AccessToken" layout="${AzureAccessToken:ResourceName=${gdc:DatabaseHostSuffix}}"  />
  </target>
</targets>
```

And then you can initialize it like this:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("DatabaseHostSuffix", $"https://{DatabaseHostSuffix}/");
NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
```

**Update** Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.1.0 (and newer) supports **Authentication**-option in the ConnectionString, that enables builtin AD authentication. This removes the need for using NLog.Extensions.AzureAccessToken.

Example with Authentication assigned to Active Directory Default:

> string ConnectionString = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Default; Database=testdb;";

See also: [Using Active Directory Default authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-default-authentication)

Comment: I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

based on [NLog official target reference](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) and Rolf indicated. NLog not provides readymade interfaces that using access token to connect to Azure SQL DB target. So I am afraid you should use Azure SQL connection string with auth information here.

If you want to avoid leaking Azure SQL server connection string with auth information or you want to make sure only your server with MSI can use NLog to write logs to Azure SQL DB, maybe it will be a workaround :

[storing your Azure SQL server connection string in Azure key-Vault](https://sqlplayer.net/2019/01/store-sensitive-information-with-azure-key-vault/) and config an access policy to make sure only your server can access it. While Nlog need to connect to Azure SQL , use server MSI to read full connecting string from key vault directly to feed Nlog target.

Comment: Hi , if there is anything unclear about my workaround , pls feel free to let me know  ：）

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Ado-IDbConnection that wraps a SqlConnection that automatically assigns AccessToken in a project called MyAssembly:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
   public class MyDbConnection : System.Data.IDbConnection
   {
      private readonly System.Data.IDbConnection _sqlConnection;

      public MyDbConnection()
      {
          var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection;
          // Could probably delay the assignment to when Open() is called
          sqlConnection.AccessToken = "Hello World";
          _sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
      }

      public string ConnectionString
      {
          get => _sqlConnection.ConnectionString;
          set => _sqlConnection.ConnectionString = value;
      }

      public int ConnectionTimeout => _sqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout;
      public string Database => _sqlConnection.Database;
      public ConnectionState State => _sqlConnection.State;
      public IDbTransaction BeginTransaction() => _sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
      public IDbTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel il) => _sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(il);
      public void ChangeDatabase(string databaseName) => _sqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(databaseName);
      public void Close() => _sqlConnection.Close();
      public IDbCommand CreateCommand() => _sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
      public void Open() => _sqlConnection.Open();
      public void Dispose() => _sqlConnection.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Then tell NLog DatabaseTarget to use your custom MyDbConnection in MyAssembly.dll:

```
<target type="database" dbprovider="MyNameSpace.MyDbConnection, MyAssembly">
</target>
```

Sorry for any compiler errors, as I have not tested the code provided, but just a random thought.

See also: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T711407/how-to-establish-sqlconnection-for-a-user-using-the-accesstoken-authentication

Comment: Lol I was confused with MySql here ;) (MySqlConnection() for SQL server?!)

Comment: Updated the code, and renamed to MyDbConnection (instead of MySqlConnection)

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) ver. 2.1.0 now supports the `Authentication`-option in the ConnectionString (removes the need to explictly assign AccessToken):

```cs
string ConnectionString = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Default; Database=testdb;";
```

`Active Directory Default` uses `DefaultAzureCredential` from Azure.Identity-package that supports the following identity-providers:

- EnvironmentCredential - Authentication to Azure Active Directory based on environment variables.
- ManagedIdentityCredential - Authentication to Azure Active Directory using identity assigned to deployment environment.
- SharedTokenCacheCredential - Authentication using tokens in the local cache shared between Microsoft applications.
- VisualStudioCredential - Authentication to Azure Active Directory using data from Visual Studio
- VisualStudioCodeCredential - Authentication to Azure Active Directory using data from Visual Studio Code
- AzureCliCredential - Authentication to Azure Active Directory using Azure CLI to obtain an access token

See also: [Using Active Directory Default authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-default-authentication)